# Simple calculation with dyads

Tags: vectors, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I'm reading a book about tensor calculus (*Tesor Calculus for Physicists*, Dwight E. Neuenschwander) that introduces dyads as a short side topic in one of the exercises (2.11). I am confused about how they are defining how a dyad can act on a vector through the regular dot product. They say $C\cdot AB$ means $(C\cdot A)B$ (where $AB$ is the dyad — I see this might be also called a dyadic, but my book says dyad).

I'm given the vectors

\begin{equation}
A=3i+2j+5k\\
B=7i+11k\\
C=2i+3j+4k
\end{equation}

and being asked to calculate $AB\cdot C$, which I assume means $A(B\cdot C)$. What I *want* to do when I see this is

\begin{equation}
A(B\cdot C)=A(14+44)=58A
\end{equation}

However, I know this is incorrect because my textbook states that the first term should be $42i$. This seems to be what you get if you take the first term of $AB$, which is $21ii$, and do $21i(i\cdot C)$. I assume you then do the same for every term of $AB$. But then, why make the assertion that $AB\cdot C = A(B\cdot C)$? That seems to mean something completely different. Any help?

Comment: At first read this looks odd. It may help if you could link us to the source material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textbook is wrong. From the equation
$$\begin{align}
AB\cdot C
&= (3i+2j+5k)(7i+11k)\cdot(2i+3j+4k) \\
&= (21ii+33ik+14ji+22jk+35ki+55kk)\cdot(2i+3j+4k)
\end{align}$$
and the condition that this last product should be expanded by distributivity,
you can see that he is failing to consider the $ji$, $ki$ and $ik$ terms of $AB$, all of which will contribute to the $i$ component of $AB\cdot C$.

You can read more on [the relevant wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Product_of_dyadic_and_vector).